# Python code deployment in saltstack

Tags: python, salt-stack

How can we deploy a python code from master to minion using saltstack? I am working on localhost.
I've done the installation things
I am not trying to completely understand it, I just want to know how the deployment could be.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on Stack Overflow. See ["Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [cmd state module](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/2017.7/ref/states/all/salt.states.cmd.html#salt.states.cmd.script) to execute a script from master to a minion,

```
run_python:
  cmd.script:
    - name: script_optional_name
    - source: salt://test/script.py
```

The script will be executed in a minion.

Comment: Thank you sir, 
but is this a configuration to put in master file ?

Comment: No, you need to create a state file in your master and then deploy that state to minion. Please if you can read some basic tutorials on saltstack.